# Двоеточие, тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, взаимозаменямы ли в этих предложениях знаки двоеточие и  длинное тире?

К великому сожалению, ответ на поставленный вопрос очевиден (:) такая вероятность сведена к минимуму.

Возникает вопрос: какова вероятность... (Можно ли здесь поставить тире или запятую?)

Поэтому новая задача должна звучать по-иному (-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В В бессоюзном сложном предложении с изъяснительно-пояснительными отношениями встречается наряду с двоеточием также тире.

> Ср.: Я понял: важно, кто рисует (Гран.); Я понял — случилось горе, и молча хотел помочь (Ес.);
>
> Ефрему казалось: не будет конца пути (Сарт.); И казалось — вот-вот немного, и Фёдор поймёт (Тендр.);
>
> Всех интересовал только один вопрос (: —) как поскорее выпутаться из создавшегося положения;
>
> На голове её цветной платок (: —) по алому полю зелёные розы;

Что касается вашего последнего предложения, чтобы дать на него ответ, необходимо полное предложение.

Запятая вместо тире в этих типах предложения не встречается.

О замене тире  запятой см.: ***Розенталь. Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.*** [Запятая — тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=190#pp190)

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ и хорошую ссылку. Последнее предложение: Поэтому новая задача должна звучать
по-иному — как нам выйти из стратегического тупика.

Comment: Т. е. в предложении "Возникает вопрос, какова вероятность того-то и того-то..." можно поставить и тире, и двоеточие, и запятую, т. к. это косвенный вопрос?

Comment: Аленка, в вашем предложении нет косвенного вопроса,т.к. после двоеточия раскрывается суть вопроса, а не сам вопрос как таковой.

Comment: В предложении  ***Поэтому новая задача должна звучать по-иному — как нам выйти из стратегического тупика***  возможно и тире и двоеточие, т.к. здесь изъяснительные отношения.

Comment: Т. е. "Она спросила, не хочу ли я чаю?" - это косвенный вопрос, а "Возникает вопрос: какова вероятность создания такой компании?" - - это не косвенный вопрос и запятая недопустима? Ведь если убрать слова "возникает вопрос", то останется сам вопрос, как таковой. Я просто хочу понять. :)

Comment: Да. В первом предложении вопрос прозвучал. Во втором - никто не задавал вопрос. Просто поясняется, какой вопрос возникает.

Comment: Серж, читая Академический справочник, наткнулась на пункт по теме: "Если придаточная часть представляет собой косвенный вопрос: Его очень беспокоил вопрос: стоит ли покупать эту книгу (Гран.); однако в таком случае допустима и запятая". Мне кажется, это как раз тот случай и предложение со словом вопрос, заключающее в себе сам вопрос, названо именно косвенным вопросом. И запятая вместо двоеточия допустима.

Comment: Аленка, в каком разделе Вы читали? Не мог ли привести ссылку?

Comment: Полный академический справочник. Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении § 125 п. 2

Comment: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134

Comment: Да, запятая допустима. Уточнил у Граммы.ру.